# ImageOverlay or VideoOverlay in ArcGIS JS API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to lay an image over my map using the ArcGIS JS API.  Whether it be a png, jpg, or gif, I'd like to be able to use a locally hosted image, give the 4 coordinates for the corners, and have that laid over my map.  I know this is super simple to do in leaflet with an `L.ImageOverlay` or `L.VideoOverlay`, but I am struggling to see any documentation or examples that can do this with the ArcGIS JS API.  I thought perhaps it could be done with a [GraphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html), but I don't see any examples.  Frankly I'm not even sure where to get started with this.  Is anyone familiar with how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the v3 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, you can do this with a [MapImageLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/mapimagelayer-amd.html), like this:

```js
var mapImageLayer = new MapImageLayer();

var img = new MapImage({
  href: myImageUrl,
  extent: {
    // replace the values here:
    xmin: 22.222,
    ymin: 40.444,
    xmax: 79.999,
    ymax: 50.555,
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 4326
    }
  }
});

mapImageLayer.addImage(img);

map.addLayer(mapImageLayer);
```

As of 2021-09, this same functionality is not yet supported in the latest v4 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Comment: Wow thanks for answering almost a year later.  I probably should have specified in the question that I needed this functionality for v4. But the project I was working on is done now and I gave up on that feature, because, as you mentioned, its not supported in v4.  Thanks!